# What is a "Public DNS registered IP address"?

Tags: dns, ip-address, top-level-domains

I've been reading [this ICANN agreement on new TLDs](http://newgtlds.icann.org/en/applicants/agb/base-agreement-specs-04jun12-en.pdf) and it has this section on DNS service availability, which i don't completely understand:

> Refers to the ability of the group of listed-as-authoritative name servers of a particular domain name (e.g., a TLD), to answer DNS queries from DNS probes. For the service to be considered available at a particular moment, at least, two of the delegated name servers registered in the DNS must have successful results from “DNS tests” to each of their **public-DNS registered “IP addresses”** to which the name server resolves. If 51% or more of the DNS testing probes see the service as unavailable during a given time, the DNS service will be considered unavailable.

I'm not 100% sure of the part in bold: does "public" refer to the DNS or to the IP addesses? It looks like there's a mistake and that the hyphen should have been after "DNS". So basically does it mean "**the public IP addresses registered in the DNS**"?

Answer (score 2):

The IP addresses of the nameservers configured to be authoritative for your domain by the registrar (e.g. GoDaddy) are the public-DNS registered “IP addresses” referred to.

Comment: Thanks Justin, so it's those IP addresses that are referred to as being public?

Comment: The ip addresses referred to are the name server for your domain. They could be GoDaddy's name servers if they are your registrar or your own servers if you are running a DNS server of our own.